# How to authenticate all pages in ng-view angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I really need help here as  I have tried to get it to work a lot of ways but did not succeed. I have index.html which has ng-view. app.js defines the routes. I want the user to be authenticated before using pages (#/home, #/groups ), however, it does not seem to work. What do I need to make to href, so that all the pages are authenticated

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJIFb.png)

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu7qo.png)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Spring boot and Angularjs Tutorial</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu-section" style="background:black;width: 100%;height: 100%" ng-app="app">
    <h1 style="color:white;text-align:center">SOF Financial</h1>
    <p style="color:white;text-align:center">Financial Information Services</p>
    <div style="text-align:center" class ="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="#/home">Home</a>
        <a href="#/indices">Indices & Commodities</a>
        <a href="#/blogs">Blogs</a>
        <a href="#/groups">Groups</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-view style="background-color: black"></div>
<script src="/webjars/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css">
```

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70zkC.png)

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngResource']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl: '/views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })
        .when('/indices',{
            templateUrl: '/views/indices.html',
            controller: 'indicesController'
        })
        .otherwise(
            { redirectTo: '/'}
        );
});
```

[MVCConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBCdp.png)

I have added the below entry to pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I want to understand how can I authenticate all pages in the view, before displaying them to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your dev level. But with your setup, you have two side. A server side with Java and a client/front end side with angularjs.
Server side will answer calls of front end and provide results. Code are on server and so hard to access 'directly'.
Application side are usually deliver all at once when web page is loaded. Once loaded, all code is available on client.

AngularJS routes them self are not existing on server side (java spring), they are declare/usable only within your angularjs app (client browser).

Plenty of ways to 'solve' your problem...some better than others but harder to do.

### Quick and 'dirty'

Define anyway all routes in angularjs modules, but have a dedicated REST/service call to fetch menu/link to allow routes and generate your navigation on that.
Of course user can still type directly route in url and access page.
Another dirty call at beginning of page to check if current route can be accessed.

### Better but still not perfect

Having a dynamic js file (Spring Controller) who return angularjs code with all available routes.
That still load all angularjs components, even if they are not used and so could give clues to potential hackers...but that's not too bad already.

### Almost perfect but still a dream?

Lasy load a list of route provided by server. Once they are accessed, source are downloaded from server. Meaning only components requested by route will be loaded.
Kind of UI application growing only with what user do/needs.
We try something in this direction in angular8 with some success.